# Would too small tubing reduce the max head of a pump?

Tags: pumps

I got a mini-project: I want to automatically get rid of the water produced by an indoor air conditioner unit. Since the unit is underground, the water needs to climb ~2m to get to the outside.

I found a cheap pump online that has a max head of 3m and flow rate of 240l/h, the pipes on it have 6mm on the inside diameter. I also have some tubing left over from a gardening project but its 4mm on the inside.

I can figure out how to fit the two together mechanically but since the tubing is tad too small, wouldn't that increase the pressure requirement and thus decrease the max head?

I really don't mind if it affects the flow rate, the amount of water I need to pump out is ~2L/day max so I'm adding a microcontroller to turn it on for just a few minutes out of a day anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [System curve for use in determining pump operating point](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16481/system-curve-for-use-in-determining-pump-operating-point)

The smaller lines will increase the resistance to flow, which will decrease the flow rate.  The use able head is reduced, but this wouldn't be a problem with such a low flow rate. However, the lines will still flow, just at a reduced flow rate.